# Is Dostarlimab approved for cancer treatments already in some countries?

Tags: cancer

This article dated 5th June 2022 [Unprecedent cancer study leaves every patient cancer free](https://www.dailywire.com/news/unprecedented-remarkable-cancer-study-leaves-every-patient-cancer-free) talks about

> "Results from a small cancer trial that left every patient in
> remission is being praised as “unprecedented” and “remarkable.”" for
> patients with "mismatch repair–deficient stage II or III rectal
> adenocarcinoma".

Now I thought, this might be one of these treatments or drugs which takes 10 years or so to be approved.

But then I found this entry dated 2021, [Dostarlimab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dostarlimab#:%7E:text=On%2017%20August%202021%2C%20the,and%20who%20have%20no%20satisfactory)

> On 17 August 2021, the US Food and Drug Administration (FDA) granted
> accelerated approval to dostarlimab for adults with mismatch repair
> deficient (dMMR) recurrent or advanced solid tumors, as determined by
> an FDA-approved test, that have progressed on or following prior
> treatment and who have no satisfactory alternative treatment options

Is this drug used in a study with "remarkable and unprecedent" results approved for use in some countries already, and if so, which kind of tumors or cancers have been approved for?

Comment: The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dostarlimab) seems to cover this in detail, is there something I'm missing, a contradiction with what you've found elsewhere?

Comment: @JiminyCricket. I find it odd that there is a study praising the drug after the drug have been approved. How was it approved if they didnt know it was good based in some prior studies? (which should have shown how good it was before 2021, yet we get the news of it giving great results in 2022) Are they talking exactly about the same treatments?

Comment: Also, the second link first refers to it being used in endometrial cancer, but then later seems to talk about it being used for tumors in general

Comment: "that have progressed on or following prior treatment and who have no satisfactory alternative treatment options" is basically "it's approved if you're certainly going to die anyways". For the FDA under ["compassionate use"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expanded_access) pretty much any drug is available in that state if a physician and patient with informed consent agree.

Comment: Whether a study is "remarkable and unprecedented" is largely a matter of opinion. Of course the study authors are going to talk up their study. But 18 patients is not that many, really. The second part of your question seems easily answered by the Wikipedia page Jiminy linked.

Comment: @IanCampbell I thought so after they announced a great "cancer vaccine", tested in animals, in hundreds of websites 4 years ago, and now you can't barely find info  about it anywhere.

Comment: @Pablo Didn't you already post a question about that one? It sounds familiar... Anyways, science doesn't work based on whatever thing the media decides to get hyped about, it works by incremental progress. There isn't one "great cancer vaccine" that failed, there are dozens or hundreds of possible treatments for various cancers developed and tested every year, many fail. There's no conspiracy there, it's just that science and medicine and cancer are **hard**, if it were easy these things wouldn't be the problems that they are.

Comment: @bryankrause yes, I posted a question about the cancer vaccine 2 years ago probably, I usually get a close relative with cancer around 8 years or so, and with the standard treatments all get the same outcome. I was hoping next time there was a promising new treatment other than surgery, radiation or chemotherapy but it doesnt seem the case.

Comment: @Pablo There *are* improvements in cancer diagnosis and treatment over time, though. E.g. https://www.cdc.gov/cancer/dcpc/research/update-on-cancer-deaths/index.htm "In the past 20 years, from 2001 to 2020, cancer death rates went down 27%, from 196.5 to 144.1 deaths per 100,000 population" If you are expecting one miracle treatment to be the solution to all cancer, you're very misled. Instead, it's small little gains in all sorts of areas: detecting slightly earlier to treat earlier, a new treatment for a specific form of a specific type of cancer, etc.